# Shopify run for loop again after clicking Check-Out button

Tags: javascript, for-loop, shopify, liquid

I'd like to run this for-loop again after clicking the checkout button, to check if the quantity is 2 oder less to set check_nike = true.
is this possible without reloading the side again after the customer set the product quantity on 2?

```
 {% for item in cart.items %}
              {% if item.title contains 'nike' %}
              {% if item.quantity > 2  %}
                  {% assign check_nike = false %}
              {% endif %}
           {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
```

I have although implemented this in my theme.liquid

```
$('body').on('click', '[name="checkout"], [name="goto_pp"], [name="goto_gc"]', function() {

    if ($('#agree').is(':checked') && {{check_nike}} == true ) {
      $(this).submit();
    }
    else {
      if({{check_nike}} == false){
       alert("You can't only order two Nike products");
      }
      else{
        document.getElementById("centerbox1").className += " forgottocheck";
      }
      return false;
    }

});
</script>
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use liquid code `{{ check_nike }}` in a JavaScript for any client side activity. Rather you can try checking the cart.js file of Shopify.

Whenever a product is added to cart use `GET` as shown in - https://docs.shopify.com/themes/development/getting-started/using-ajax-api#get-cart to see if you specific condition matches.

Going further you can also use `localStorage` or cookies to reduce the number of `GET` calls by storing specific cart information locally.